# How can I say - think yourself (думай сам in russian)

Tags: meaning, word-choice

How can I say - think yourself (думай сам in russian)
Help please.
Thank you.

Comment: What meaning are you trying to give? Without context there are any number of possible meanings. "think for yourself",  "think of yourself", "think about yourself", "don't tell me to think, think yourself", "imagine yourself in the following situation"  and others. Also, probably best to ask this question on the English Language Learners forum. https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage!  Very few of us here know Russian.  In order to understand your question, we need context.  In English it is possible to say "Think for yourself" as an individual sentence. However we can also use the phrase "think yourself" as a reflexive fragment of a sentence.  EDIT I have just seen the comment by @Pete and agree with that.

Comment: Note that you may get good answers from from https://russian.stackexchange.com/ 
 and from https://forum.wordreference.com/forums/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-russian.93/  They tend to be more bilingual.

Comment: Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this from the song? Then, I would translate it as "Think for yourself!"

Comment: @Grek - Please note that if a phrase comes from a song, this should be mentioned in the question with a link if possible. This is also true for any text that you quote. Please give the name of the author and the name of the work. Otherwise we have to guess and it makes things harder for us. I hope this helps!